# wxPython - scaling UI elements with window?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

When I scale the window in my wxPython app, the elements remain the same size, so if I shrink it, some of them are "cut off" from view. How do I make everything scale with the window? Is it even possible in wx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use *sizers* to control layout in wxPython, including scaling widgets.

Here is a tutorial:

http://userpages.umbc.edu/~dhood2/courses/cmsc433/spring2012/?section=Notes&topic=Python&notes=14